# play store update error code: -1

Tags: android

I am updating my app on android store but my some user can not update app on android play store.

There is seen "Update" button on app
[image: Android App Store Update Button]
When user click to "Update"
[image: Update error]

It gives Error Code: -1   I can not find -1 Error code.

%50 users updates new version, %50 users is not update.
[image: Android Play Console Screenshot]

Do you have any idea to solve this problem? I was tried upload new version after and after but it is not working.

Comment: getting this too, how did you solve it @user448283?